# How clear markers in function setMarkers(map, markers)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I have the function:

```
function setMarkers(map, markers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var stores = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[1], stores[2]);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                icon: image,
                map: map,
                title: stores[0],
                html: stores[4]
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
```

I need the toggle button in html page to hide and show the markers in the map, how i do this?

P.S I try to setMap(null), but she does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep references to the google.maps.Marker objects.

```
var gmarkers = [];

function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var stores = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stores[1], stores[2]);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            icon: image,
            map: map,
            title: stores[0],
            html: stores[4]
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
```

Then to hide the first marker `gmarkers[0].setMap(null)`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to show and hide markers.

I did 
`var markersArray = [];



 markersArray.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

function clearOverlays() {
        setAllMap(null);
      }

    function showOverlays() {
        setAllMap(map);
      }

    function setAllMap(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
          markersArray[i].setMap(map);
        }
    };`

But map is not defined.